# counting grouped missing values in R

Tags: r, group-by, missing-data

Sorry if this question is fairly simple

I am new to R and I want to count by group the number of missing values in the column `some_column`, which are in my dataset replaces by `0` values, and then get the group which has maximum of `0` values. So did this  (using package `dplyr`):

```
missing_data <- group_by(some_data,some_group, count=sum(some_column==0))
```

But what is weird is that I get in the `count` column the same number all along the dataset as if the dataset was not grouped. Someone has an idea

Ok I got it

missing_data %>% group_by(some_group) %>% summarise(count=sum(some_column==0))

Comment: Did you take a look at a dplyr introduction tutorial?

Comment: @docendodiscimus thank you for your response. Yes, and that's the reason why I tried what I posted. Am I going wrong ?

Comment: I think you're still missing an understanding of the most basic dplyr functions, i.e. group_by, mutate, summarise, filter, and select. If you understand those, you can already do a lot and probably solve your problem

Comment: @docendodiscimus thank you for your pedagogical invotation to better understand. I just realise that I copy-paste wrong command I ran. I edited my post in this sense, which does not exempt me from going further in `dplyr` documentation ;)

Comment: Your attempt shows that you have not yet understood that you have to first group the data (using group_by) and _afterwards_ compute the number of NA or 0s (using mutate or summarise). What you do is create a grouping variable "count" that is the same for all rows because your data has not yet been grouped before that step

Comment: well done! Now the right way to show that you've solved your question (or anyone else's question for that matter) is to post the solution as an answer instead of adding it to the question. You can then accept your own answer, too.

Comment: Add, to the end of the pipe, `%>% arrange(desc(count))` to move the group with the highest count of `0` values up to the first row in the output. See my answer below for an example.

Comment: @docendodiscimus thank you, I have added an answer

Comment: @Odysseus210 perfect I add this at the end of my answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's finally the answer

```
missing_data %>% group_by(some_group) %>% summarise(count=sum(some_column==0)) %>% arrange(desc(count))
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping with `dplyr` verbs:

```
missing_data <- filter(some_data, some_column == 0) %>%
  group_by(some_group) %>%       
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(count))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example using mtcars dataframe

```
count_zero<-function(x){
  sum(x==0,na.rm=TRUE)
}
aggregate(mtcars,list(cyl=(mtcars$cyl)),count_zero)
```

Comment: as I said in my post I am looking for `0` values

Comment: it would be this : `library(magrittr);aggregate(airquality,list(Month=airquality$Month),. %>% equals(0) %>% sum(na.rm=TRUE))` but in this dataset you'll have only zeroes in the output, as there is no zero in the input

Comment: Hi, I edited the example, but honestly you can look for whatever you want, It doesn not change that much, you just have to change the auxiliary function